# Nature as a calculator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-computer, computational-physics, computer

I wondered whether physical experiments can find the outcome of otherwise intractable mathematical problems.

For example, solitons or other non-perturbative effects in QFT cannot be seen at any order in perturbation theory, and are difficult to calculate, but could in principle be measured. Is nature doing the whole path integral/the whole perturbative expansion at once? Does that mean a computer could, in principle do it, in a finite time? or can nature solve math problems that are otherwise impossible?

Comment: In my opinion, this contains the philosophical question, whether reality as we perceive it is really a simulation.

Comment: Nature solves problems simply by having all the variables and letting the system evolve as it should. We try to predict the solution without actually having it happen at the same time and we don't include all the variables

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about philosophy of science (or complexity theory, depending on how you look at it). The question whether nature "carries out" the mathematical calculations we use to describe it or if our descriptions are laughable inept attempts to make nature comprehensible is not, in any way, physically answerable.

Comment: @ACuriousMind don't be so prescriptive!

Comment: in any case, if it could be shown that the whole path integral was impossible to compute in a finite time (has it?) we would have an answer (either nature not doing whole path integral or something else strange), so it isn't just a matter of debate, or is it?

Comment: While I am not possessing any proof of it, I'm pretty sure that nature is not actually calculating anything, it's just doing it. Much in the same way you don't need to calculate *how* to throw a baseball, you just do it.

Comment: @KyleKanos yes, but the fact you *can* throw a baseball, means that throwing a baseball is possible ;) does the fact that nature can *just do* the PI, mean that it is possible for me to calculate it? if not, can I use nature as a special calculator to do it for me!?

Comment: @innisfree: Perhaps you missed the part where I said *nature is not actually calculating anything*, so it can't be your special calculator. The fact that you *can* throw a baseball is irrelevant to the fact that you don't *calculate* to do it, you simply act.

Comment: @innisfree as I said, nature has access to all the variables. Every last one. It knows the effect a lone electron 6 million light years away is having on the baseball and everything in between.

Comment: Surprising that this question was closed as off-topic. At worst I would say it is too broad; and someone who really knows the subject should be able to give an overview. At best I can point out interesting fragments, like Michael Freedman showing that "TQFTs cannot be used to define a model of computation stronger than the usual quantum model BQP" http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0001071